# Regular Expression - Capture a group with specific character

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have below string

```
[ string1] [ string2.0 \ string2.1 ] [ string3]
```

I am looking to capture the content `"string2.0 \ string2.1"` , this could be in any position in the string, basically I want to capture the group which is insides "[  ]" and have a "\".

I have this regex - `(\[.*?\\.*?\])` but this captures the first two groups, where as I need the string from the second group only. Also, second group can occur anywhere, such as

```
[ string2.0 \ string2.1 ] [ string1] [ string3]
[ string1] [ string3] [ string2.0 \ string2.1 ]
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to replace first `.*?` with an expression that excludes square brackets:

```
\[([^[]*\\.*?)]
```

Now the capture cannot include an open square bracket, so only one group would be captured.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/vfUWKq/1)